# Manhwa about a guy who is transmigrated to a Murim and now has a System

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

He is transmigrated to a [Murim](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/s7zwyz/explanation_of_the_murim_martial_arts_world/) world and now he has a game like system. The system's first task is to create a sect and take in a disciple. He takes in a chubby guy as his first disciple. After that, the game system gives him a reward to summon a sword master and, at the start, his whole sect is just a hut. After some chapters, the system gives him a token-looking thing as a reward that is a key to a sect in a separate small world.

Comment: What do mean by a "system"?

Comment: @Buzz: "a system" is a term generally used for the person having access to something lik a game UI, generally one which allows leveling via XP and quests.

Comment: @ExpenderSir: [Solo Leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo_Leveling)

Comment: This is kinda broad. Because this is a typical trend in manhua. Mostly about building sect/family/tribe with a system.